# Replace the text numbers string in a txt file using C++

Tags: c++

For example:

**Before Document:**

> hai hello my daily salary is two thousand and five and your salary is five billion. my age is twenty-five.

**After Document:**

> hai hello my daily salary is # and your salary is #. my age is  #.

All the text numbers and i put the # symbol.. Please give me any idea..

Comment: is that text document created by you [who generates the text] or is it a puzzle or homework?

Comment: Well, you're going to have to specify an exact syntax of number formats that you want to accept. The English has many. For instance one hundred, a hundred, one-hundred, the list goes on and on. If you don't want to specify this syntax then it basically becomes an AI problem.

Comment: You are looking for regular expression. Use regular expression to replace [one|two|three|......|ten|eleven|.......|twenty|thirty|.....|hundred|....|trillion|-]+  with #

Comment: @user534498's got a good approach... it's a little tricky though - basically need to handle "a" followed by "hundred", "thousand", "million" etc. (maybe "dozen", "score" if you care), then any non-alpha and whitespace separators that are followed by other "numeric" words, then "and" iff it's followed by more numeric words.  Regexps save the minor hassle of writing a lexer front-end to separate alpha words from puntuation.  Boost spirit is another easy way to parse this, but takes some learning.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the document you wish to process and open a temporary file in append mode.
2. Read a line from the document. (I'm assuming you don't need to process numbers that span lines. If you do, you'll need to specify the problem more precisely.)
3. Replace any numbers found in the in-memory copy of that line.
4. Write the (possibly modified) line to the temporary file.
5. Loop to step 2 until you have processed all lines of the original file.
6. If desired, move the modified file on top of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Create a `vector<string>` that contains all words that are related with numbers, including

   > {"zero","one ","two ","three ","four ","five ","six ",
   >                   "seven ","eight ","nine "}
   >
   > {"twenty ","thirty ","forty ","fifty ","sixty ",
   >                   "seventy ","eighty ","ninety "}
   >
   > {"hexillion ","quintillion ","quadrillion ","trillion ","billion ","million ",
   >                       "thousand ","hundred ",""}
   >
   > {"ten ","eleven ","twelve ","thirteen ",
   >                       "fourteen ","fifteen ","sixteen ","seventeen ","eighteen "
   >                           ,"nineteen "};
2. Scan word-by-word of the text (take care of punctuation marks like `',', '.'` etc), if the word contains any one of the above `vector<string>`, replace it with `#`.